# CSS file can be changed or deleted but the css on-page doesnt change

Tags: html, css

I've just encountered something quite confusing, I've got a page named chat.php linked to a CSS doc named main.css, in folder stylesheets. If I damage the link, the CSS goes away off the page when I reload, but I can keep the link, but delete the files it links, and somehow it doesn't affect the style, it's as if it's still receiving info from a CSS file that doesn't exist, how can this even happen?

Comment: are you using any of the cache plugin to speed up the website?

Comment: Can you add some random query string to the css link and check if that reflects on page or not? For example give the css link like <link href="main.css?v=123" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: could you be a bit more specific about what you mean? not to be a pain- the word query is a bit scaryXD

Comment: cache plugin? not that i know of, there's nothing that i know of implemented that's showing a cached version of the page, if it was, what would that look like?

Comment: i added the query thing, it made all the CSS go off of the page like damaging the link did.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I simply needed to wait a few mins after each change before reloading, the page didn't respond to the changes instantly as in the past.